# AngularJS - why is the ng-click handler not being fired?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

Here's the HTML:

```
    <tr data-ng-repeat="a in assignments" data-ng-click="vm.handleAssignmentClicked()">
        ...
    </tr>
```

Here are the associated directive and controller:

```
angular
    .module('app.assignments')
    .directive('stfrAssignments', assignmentsDirective)
    .controller('AssignmentsController', AssignmentsController);

function assignmentsDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/assignments/assignments.html',
        scope: {
            assignments: '='
        },
        controller: 'AssignmentsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
    return directive;
}

function AssignmentsController() {
    var vm = this;

    function handleAssignmentClicked() {
        console.log('handleAssignmentClicked');
    }
}
```

When I click an assignment (a row in the table), the `handleAssignmentClicked()` function is not being called. Where should I look for the problem?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon the directive ***is*** using `controllerAs: 'vm'` already in this code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: As pointed out by a comment, the parent directive (which we supposed is being used) is using the `controllerAs` syntax, which is addressed in the second point [2]. I leave the first one for information.

[1] The `this` keyword in your controller is not the same as its `$scope`, unless you use the `contoller as controllerName` syntax.

You can inject `$scope` in your controller:

```
function AssignmentsController($scope) {
  $scope.handleAssignmentClicked() {
    console.log('handleAssignmentClicked');
  }
}
```

[2] Or alternatively, which is your case:

```
<div ng-controller="AssignmentsController as assignCtrl">
...
  <tr data-ng-repeat="a in assignCtrl.assignments" data-ng-click="assignCtrl.handleAssignmentClicked()">
```

And in your controller you would use `this` to make the function accessible:

```
this.handleAssignmentClicked = function() { ... }
```

Comment: @Claies indeed, so we fall into my second case where the function should be assigned to `this`

Comment: (I have updated my answer based on your comment, thanks for pointing this out)

Comment: right, that's the issue there... good catch, the `this.` missing

Comment: @floribon, Claies, thanks for the help. That's was exactly the issue.